# unable to call c++ function from java cocos2dx

Tags: java, android, c++, cocos2d-x

I have completed my gameplay section of my game and now i am working on facebook integration with cocos2dx. I have successfully integrated facebook with cocos2dx, i.e. i can call facbook features(ex inviting friends, sharing , posting scores etc) using JNI...

but the problem i am facing is that i cannot call any c++ function from java.

i am facing similar problem as mentioned in the link below:
[Calling C++(cocos2dx) method from java(android) for my in-app billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792562/calling-ccocos2dx-method-from-javaandroid-for-my-in-app-billing)

i have also read the tutorial given in the forum:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_use_jni

and also:
http://purplelilgirl.tumblr.com/post/54583532324/code-bit-how-to-use-jni-in-cocos2dx-android

Although i have read the above tutorials but it is still not very much clear to me about how to get started with it.
can any one provide me with a detailed help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java call c not c++ , so you need

java code(call jniPrintSomething(0) when you need):

```
public static native int jniPrintSomething(int val);
```

cpp code:

```
extern "C" {
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
    jint Java_org_reanix_bubbleshooter_BubbleShooter_jniPrintSomething(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,jint val){
        return 0;
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to use the if(targetplatform == android) ??